# Link clicked first time - on scroll animation doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, scroll, eventtrigger

**Issue:**

When I click the `skill-set` link for the first time, the animation occurs but does not occur when you scroll down.  Each circle is to start it's own animation when the user scrolls down the page.  If you click the `skill-set` link twice though, everything works as its supposed to.

So my question at hand is, why doesn't the animation `on scroll` occur on the first time the `skill-set` link is clicked?

Here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/de41cppa/8/) of what I am talking about, please excuse the terrible layout.  Once you click on the `skill-set` link, you see the animation happen, but when you scroll down, the animation is already completed...However, if you click the `skill-set` link twice, and then scroll down, you see each circle animate when you scroll down.  This is what should happen on the first time the link is clicked, but for some odd reason it isn't.

**JS:**

```
$('#skill-set-link').click(function () {

    function animateElements(index, element) { // (e, init)
        if (element) { // (init)
            $('.progressbar').data('animate', false);
        }

        $('.progressbar').each(function () {
            var elementPos = $(this).offset().top;
            var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
            var percent = $(this).find('.circle').attr('data-percent');
            var percentage = parseInt(percent, 10) / parseInt(100, 10);
            var animate = $(this).data('animate');

            if (elementPos < topOfWindow + $(window).height() + 10 && !animate) {
                $(this).data('animate', true);
                $(this).find('.circle').circleProgress({
                    startAngle: -Math.PI / 2,
                    value: percent / 100,
                    thickness: 2, // Change this for thickness
                    fill: {
                        color: '#16A085'
                }
                }).on('circle-animation-progress', function (event, progress, stepValue) {
                    $(this).find('.percent').text((stepValue * 100).toFixed(0) + "%"); // NOTE: Change '.toFixed(0)' to '.toFixed(1)' to get 1 decimal place to the right...
                }).stop();
            }
        });

    }
    animateElements({}, true);
    $('.about_body_wrapper').scroll(animateElements);
});
```

=========================================================================

Any idea as to why the animation `on scroll` doesn't occur the first time the link is clicked?

Comment: Not sure how to fix it yet, but elementPos is zero for every progressbar when animateElements runs the first time.  I think it is because that is state of those objects (i.e., hidden), when the link is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help from Tony Hinkle - Here is the answer.

Due to the main div being hidden - we needed to `show()` the main div beforehand...However, adding `$('#skill-set').show(0, animateElements);` as suggested by Tony, didn't quite work right - so instead `$('#skill-set').fadeIn(animateElements)` replaced that along with taking out the `0` which seemed to do the trick.

Many thanks to Tony though for steering me in the right direction!

Here is the final snippet used to make this work as desired:

```
function animateElements(index, element) { // (e, init)

    $('.progressbar').each(function () {
        var elementPos = $(this).offset().top;
        var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
        var percent = $(this).find('.circle').attr('data-percent');
        var percentage = parseInt(percent, 10) / parseInt(100, 10);
        var animate = $(this).data('animate');

        if (elementPos < topOfWindow + $(window).height() + 10 && !animate) {
            $(this).data('animate', true);
            $(this).find('.circle').circleProgress({
                startAngle: -Math.PI / 2,
                value: percent / 100,
                thickness: 2, // Change this for thickness
                fill: {
                    color: '#16A085'
                }
            }).on('circle-animation-progress', function (event, progress, stepValue) {
                $(this).find('.percent').text((stepValue * 100).toFixed(0) + "%"); // NOTE: Change '.toFixed(0)' to '.toFixed(1)' to get 1 decimal place to the right...
            }).stop();
        }
    });

}

$('#skill-set-link').click(function () {
    $('.progressbar').data('animate', false);
    $('#skill-set').fadeIn(animateElements);
});

$(window).scroll(animateElements);
```

And here is the final iteration: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/de41cppa/10/)

Don't mind the layout... :)

Answer (score 1):

The behavior is occurring because everything in the skill-set-link DIV is still hidden when it runs the first time, so the top position of all of the progressbar elements is zero.  Since they are zero, they are meeting the criteria of the if statement and the animation is being enabled on all of them.

To fix it, I added a call to `show()` the progressbar elements, including the parameter to run animateElements when `show()` is complete.

I moved the call to set "animate" to false to the menu item click function as it didn't really serve any purpose in animateElements.  I also removed the animateElements function from the click event handler to simplify reading the code.

```
function animateElements(index, element) { // (e, init)

    $('.progressbar').each(function () {
        var elementPos = $(this).offset().top;
        var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
        var percent = $(this).find('.circle').attr('data-percent');
        var percentage = parseInt(percent, 10) / parseInt(100, 10);
        var animate = $(this).data('animate');

        if (elementPos < topOfWindow + $(window).height() + 10 && !animate) {
            $(this).data('animate', true);
            $(this).find('.circle').circleProgress({
                startAngle: -Math.PI / 2,
                value: percent / 100,
                thickness: 2, // Change this for thickness
                fill: {
                    color: '#16A085'
                }
            }).on('circle-animation-progress', function (event, progress, stepValue) {
                $(this).find('.percent').text((stepValue * 100).toFixed(0) + "%"); // NOTE: Change '.toFixed(0)' to '.toFixed(1)' to get 1 decimal place to the right...
            }).stop();
        }
    });

}

$('#skill-set-link').click(function () {
    $('.progressbar').data('animate', false);
    $('#skill-set').fadeIn(animateElements);
});

$(window).scroll(animateElements);
```

Comment: This is very close! I am not using the `$(window).scroll(animateElements);`, instead, I'm using `$('.about_body_wrapper').scroll(animateElements);` for a specific reason...and when I change `window` to `.about_body_wrapper`, for some reason, on first click, the circles do not appear at all until you start to scroll down. I ended up taking out the `0,` in `$('#skill-set').show(0, animateElements);` which helped, but doing that adds an odd display where everything flows in from the left side which is not desired...

Comment: Any idea how to fix this?  Sadly, I am unable to use `$(window).scroll(animateElements);` - I had to write that in for the jsFiddle though for it to work on there...but in actuality, I'm using `$('.about_body_wrapper')...`and with what you have, it still doesn't work quite right...Here is the latest iteration: http://jsfiddle.net/de41cppa/9/ - Everything should fade in rather than sliding in from the left....Any ideas?

Comment: Scratch all that....I think I got it.  Here is the latest iteration now: http://jsfiddle.net/de41cppa/10/ - Thank you Tony for steering me in the right direction!

Comment: For some reason, it rejected my edit on your post so that it would be correct - if you add what I have done on that latest iteration from the jsFiddle, I'll accept your answer Tony!

Comment: @Michael I've made the change.  Thanks!